# Is the model over-fitting the data?

Tags: machine-learning, overfitting

On the y-axis you've got RMSE and on the x-axis you've got the number of epochs. Then in blue, the validation error, in red the training error.

What do you think is the optimal number of epochs before the model starts overfitting? I would go with 74 epochs.

[image]

Comment: Best checkpoint would be the one where validation loss stops decreasing further and remains constant. In your case as you said it would be around epoch 70. Or you can add early stopping in your algorithm so that model itself would take care of the point where it needs to stop training further.

Comment: What a great answer! But I also read that too many epochs may cause over-fitting also... so, we have to make a good choice.

Comment: Yea. That is true. I had faced similar issues few days back while doing image classification. Is there any possibility you could increase the number of samples ?

Comment: somewhere around 60+. By 74 you are already in a steady validation error while training error is decreasing. that will lead most probably to overfitting